# Terminal Opens But does not respond to any input. ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

I was mucking about in some neovim configuration.
I decided to restart my machine and now when I open a terminal it opens but ignores all inputs. I can type whatever I want, but it doesn't show the username or any other information and it doesn't respond when I press enter.

This is the case in both terminator and the default gnome-terminal.

I have tried restarting multiple times, and if I press CTRL + ALT + F3 I can get into a login screen. I can login to a normal terminal session but that also is non-responsive in the same way. I log in, and then the text-based display is completely useless.

How can I fix this? Especially considering I cannot access the terminal to try many things I would normally try on my own.

In the meantime, I have checked dmesg, dpkg and syslog in /var/log/. The only thing that stood out as suspicious was a half install of neovim. I had uninstalled the most recent version and attempted to re-install the next version but it failed to overwrite an existing file from the previous install right before restart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted into recovery mode looked at some logs I couldn't see without root permissions.
Then I realized I probably need to smash Ctrl-C in the terminal and that worked. I got a working terminal. Some process was running on terminal start every time.
I'll update this if I figure out what that is, but in the meantime the original question I asked is solved.

Edit: My bashrc had an unfinished command saved in it. So it was trying to run the bashrc script and hanging.